# OpenCl cannot compile kernel with 'printf'

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I am getting the error

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'printf' is invalid in OpenCL
```

when I try to build an OpenCL kernel. The kernel code is this

```c
__kernel void conj_grad(int dim, int num_vals, __local float *r,                
      __local float *x, __local float* A_times_p, __local float *p,             
      __global int *rows, __global int *cols, __global float *A,                
      __global float *b, __global float *result) {                              
                                                                                
   local float alpha, r_length, old_r_dot_r, new_r_dot_r;                       
   local int iteration;                                                         
                                                                                
   int id = get_local_id(0);                                                    
   int start_index = -1;                                                        
   int end_index = -1;                                                          
   float Ap_dot_p;                                                              
                                                                                
   printf("OpenCL Kernel ID: %d\n", id);
```

This gives me the error below

```
input.cl:14:4: error: implicit declaration of function 'printf' is invalid in OpenCL
input.cl:14:4: note: did you mean 'rint'?
/usr/include/clc/math/unary_decl.inc:1:39: note: 'rint' declared here
/usr/include/clc/math/rint.h:2:24: note: expanded from macro '__CLC_FUNCTION'
input.cl:46:45: warning: double precision constant requires cl_khr_fp64, casting to single precision
```

I am getting a negative return code from this function `err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

I have already tried the solutions from these questions

- [Using printf() in OpenCL kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375546/using-printf-in-opencl-kernel) and
- [printf function doesn't work in OpenCL kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782388/printf-function-doesnt-work-in-opencl-kernel),

and neither of these solutions fix it. When I try these solutions, I see a warning such as `input.cl:1:26: warning: unknown OpenCL extension 'cl_amd_printf' - ignoring`

### Conclusion

Looks like my system does not support the `printf` extensions. The code below (stealing from pmdj's answer) gives me the following output. Looks like a classic story of don't depend on vendor specific extensions to a standard.

```c
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <CL/cl.h>                                                              
                                                                                
int main(void) {                                                                
    char ext_str[1024] = "";                                                    
    size_t ext_str_len = sizeof(ext_str) - 1;                                   
    cl_device_id device_id;                                                     
    cl_int err;                                                                 
    cl_platform_id platform;                                                    
                                                                                
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);                                 
    if(err < 0) {                                                               
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");                                 
        exit(1);                                                                
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);       
    if(err < 0) {                                                               
        perror("Couldn't access any devices");                                  
        exit(1);                                                                
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, sizeof(ext_str), ext_str, &ext_str_len);
    if(err < 0) {                                                               
        perror("Couldn't get device info");                                     
        exit(1);                                                                
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    printf("CL extensions (%lu): '%s'\n", ext_str_len, ext_str);                
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

```
CL extensions (248): 'cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_fp16'
```

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786682/13929340 and this  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58621074/13929340 help ?

Comment: OpenCL does not support `printf`. Some implementations support it as an extension, others maybe don't. Printing from a kernel doesn't generally make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, `printf` isn't part of standard OpenCL, but some implementations offer extensions which enable it.

To check for extensions supported by your implementation, try something like this:

```
char ext_str[1024] = "";
size_t ext_str_len = sizeof(ext_str) - 1;
err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, sizeof(ext_str), ext_str, &ext_str_len);
printf("CL extensions (%lu): '%s'\n", ext_str_len, ext_str);
```

If there aren't any `cl_*_printf` extensions listed, you are probably out of luck. If one is listed, you'll need to enable it as described in the other answers you linked. You might also want to check the specification for the specific extension yours supports in case it exhibits any particular quirks.

Comment: This is certainly more accurate. Do you reccommend I delete mine ?

Comment: @APJo Honestly, I don't think your answer adds anything particularly useful, but it's up to you of course.

Comment: Appreciate the honesty, I'll remove mine, I don't intend to give bad answers :)

Comment: @APJo Sounds sensible. I try to be positive about people's contributions on this site, but it's usually not helpful to answer questions about technology you've never used, at least not without some deeper research. To be fair, the asker probably mis-tagged the question with the `c` tag, which perhaps led you to think it was about regular C code. (FWIW, I will occasionally try to answer questions I don't immediately know the exact answer to - it can be a great way of learning - so don't be discouraged. Sometimes it works out and I can help AND learn, sometimes I find myself out of my depth.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are the supported OpenCL extensions device specific, or is it simply up to the driver?

Comment: It's conceivable that some drivers make the feature available on some devices but not others, but I'd expect that in most cases, if a driver supports the feature, it will expose it for all devices it supports. Support may vary from version to version of course.